# Add line separator in context menu of Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, menuitem

I have a menu contribution to the Package Explorer from an Eclipse plugin.
It looks like this:

```xml
<plugin>    
   <extension
         point="org.eclipse.ui.menus">
      <menuContribution
            locationURI="popup:org.eclipse.jdt.ui.PackageExplorer">
         <command
               commandId="org.attrx.actions.Open"
               style="push">
            <visibleWhen
                  checkEnabled="false">
               <iterate>
                  <adapt
                        type="org.eclipse.core.resources.IFile">
                     <test
                           property="org.eclipse.core.resources.name"
                           value="*.java">
                     </test>
                  </adapt>
               </iterate>
            </visibleWhen>
         </command>
      </menuContribution>
   </extension>
   <extension
         point="org.eclipse.ui.commands">
      <command
            defaultHandler="org.attrx.actions.Open"
            id="org.attrx.actions.Open"
            name="Open File">
      </command>
   </extension>    
</plugin>
```

I would like to add a separator line in the context menu before and after this command. Could someone help me achieve this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use

```xml
<separator
       name="separator-id"
       visible="true">
</separator>
```

before and after the `<command>`.

Note: Separators are not shown if they are at the beginning or end of a menu.

Comment: Your note explains why they weren't shown when I tried them. Thank you!

Comment: I am trying the same way, but When I try to add separator for toolbar at the end or beginning  it is not taking how can we achieve that?

Comment: @Ganesh Separators are only shown when there are menu items above and below. I don't know of a way to add them at the beginning or end.